# "text()" property of xpath is not working for a textnode as per the below mentioned code through Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Code:

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="tab">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p><span>01</span></p>
              <p class="className"><span id="">parent</span>
                Child 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

"parent" and "child" are in same p tag. I can easily locate "parent" with:

```
//*[@id="tab"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p/span
```

but can't able to locate "child" separately.

I tried with all the possibilities mentioned below, but of no use,

```
//*[@id="tab"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p/text()
//*[@id="tab"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p/text()[contains(.,'child')]
```

All the above queries are working fine in online editor but when I run it in java ide, it is showing "element absent on the page"!

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Can you provide a full java code example? I guess You should call some of http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/ commands.

Comment: Ok, can you try this with CSS selector because they are cleaner and avoid XPath

Comment: Exactly, CSS selector is lot easier, but I guess in this scenario, we can only locate this element through xpath! because it is raw text combined with other child tags,inside p tag

Comment: @DebanjanB Not for extracting the text, giving it's exact DOM position to the selenium, so that it directly navigates to that place through the locator(in this case: xpath)!

Answer (score 2):

Though both the elements with text as **parent** and **child** are in same `<p>` tag with *class* attribute as **className**, the element with text as **parent** is a decedent `<span>` node, where as the element with text as **child** is a *decedent **text node***. So though *Selenium* which uses [XPath v1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) can locate the element with text as **parent** but won't be able to locate the *text node* with text as **child**. Of-coarse can extract the text **child**.

Hence my counter question was *...What do you want to do with the text? Simply extract the text?...*.

To extract the text **child** you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id="tab"]//p[@class='className']"));
String myText = (String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", myElement);
```

Comment: Thankyou! But I don't want to extract the text, I want to locate the text node through selenium individually, which I found is not possible!

Comment: @DheerajN That is what I exactly mentioned in my answer as in **but won't be able to locate the text node with text as uploaded**. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The `text()` in your xpath `.../p[2]/text()` require to return a TextNode. But selenium can only return Element Node.

For example: `//*[@id="tab"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]/span` expect to return an Element Node which TAG name is `span`.

Galen Framework uses Selenium in order to open web browser and select the tested elements on page.

Browser supports `//*[@id="tab"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]/text()`,  you can succeed in browser's DevTool. But it's not equivalent to Selenium support too.

So in your case, you need to make selenium to find and return the `p` Element Node:

```
<p class="className"><span id="">parent</span>
    child
</p>
```

Java example of using HTML DOM API:

```
((JavaScriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
      "return arguments[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue;",
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(
          "//*[@id='tab']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]"
      ))
)
// arguments[0] is the p ElementNode
// childNodes[2] is the 3rd child node of the p, it's the TextNode 'child'
// As I mentioned, Selenium's findElement(s) not support to return TextNode
// Even you can directly access the text node via HTML DOM api, but
// you can't return it for further using by Galen.
```

Comment: Using HTML DOM API you can directly find the 'uploaded',  could you tell me what 's your next step if you find the 'uploaded', so that I can give example code for you.

Comment: You want to check the CSS value of the text node 'uploaded', is right?

Comment: exactly! Checking is taken care by Galenframework, I just have to give the exact locator.

Comment: I think Galen can't do that on text node 'uploaded',  due to Selenium can't return TextNode.

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
"//p[contains(text(), 'uploaded')]"
```

works with Selenium 3. But as yong mentioned, Selenium can only work with elements. So you could then use

```
element.getText();
element.getAttribute("textContent");
```

to get the text inside the paragraph.